# Memory leak using cvCopy

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, opencv

I have a memory leak problem using the cvCopy function of OpenCV. If I comment that line it's all ok. If not the memory raises until the system crashes..

I've found this interesting article about OpenCV memory leaks: http://www.andol.info/hci/963.htm but if I comment the line:
`targetImage = cvCreateImage( ....`

I get another problem because it says that I'm passing a null pointer.

```
..... //other code (here we are inside a loop
cvSetImageROI(&tmpimag,TargetRect);
targetImage = cvCreateImage( cvSize(TargetRect.width, TargetRect.height), tmpimag.depth, tmpimag.nChannels );
cvCopy(&tmpimag,targetImage);
cvResetImageROI(&tmpimag); // release image ROI 
....//other code
```

Answer (score 3):

For what I can tell based on your little snippet of code, the mem leak might be your fault.

On each iteration of the loop you are creating/allocating a new image with `cvCreateImage()`, but I don't see you releasing it (check `cvReleaseImage()`). Therefore, after each iteration, more and more memory is allocated generating a genuine mem leak.

**EDIT**:

`cvResetImageROI(&tmpimag);` **does not release an image**, it just resets the ROI information previously set. You still need to `cvReleaseImage(&tmpimag)`.

Comment: I'm releasing it at the beginning of the loop

Comment: By the way which version are you using?

Comment: FOUND THE MEMORY LEAK, it was not this cvCopy the problem! sorry and thank you very much for the hints

Comment: @davan It's important to us that you review the answers and either accept the one that solved your problem or **vote up** those that really helped you.

Comment: @karlphillip I don't find the button to thank! I'm not registered so maybe it's that the reason.. could it be? I can't find neither the button to accept the answer..

Answer (score 0):

are you releasing targetImage each time the loop iterates?

Comment: I'm releasing it at the beginning of the loop yes

Comment: FOUND THE MEMORY LEAK, it was not this cvCopy the problem! sorry and thank you very much for the hints